# Request doesn't match any route

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I'm building rest API to get a product using its sku, but it give me this message "Request doesn't match any route" although the url in webapi.xml file is the same in the request.
magento version is 2.1.15

here is **module.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">

   <module name="Bit68_Mobileapp" setup_version="2.1.15"/>

</config>
```

here is **di.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="\Bit68\Mobileapp\Api\Product\ProductInterface" type="\Bit68\Mobileapp\Model\Product\Product"/>
</config>
```

here is the **webapi.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<route url="/V1/status" method="GET">
    <service class="\Bit68\Mobileapp\Api\Product\ProductInterface" method="getStatus"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

here is the **`interface`**  -

```
<?php

namespace Bit68\Mobileapp\Api\Product;

 interface ProductInterface{
/**
 * get test Api data.
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStatus();}?>
```

and that is the implementation for the interface

```
<?php

namespace Bit68\Mobileapp\Model\Product;

use Bit68\Mobileapp\Api\Product\ProductInterface;

class Product implements ProductInterface{
/**
* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
*/
private $productRepository; 


/**
* @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
*/
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}


/**
* get test Api data.
*
* @api
*
* @return string
*/

function getStatus()
{
    //echo "helllloooo";
    $product=$this->$productRepository->get('pro');

    return "found";
}


}

?>
```

my request is http://127.0.0.1/yourParts/rest/V1/status/Authorization:Bearer_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

You are sending token in URL whereas your URL should be like `V1/status`. Send bearer token in header instead of URL `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN`.

And I think as this is anonymous api so you don't need to send token in this.

Comment: I have the same problem when I remove token from URL 
http://127.0.0.1/yourParts/rest/V1/status/

Comment: You are hitting get request?

Comment: Yes, does that need different url?

Comment: No just verifying. Is your project name correct yourParts?

Comment: Yes, it is ....

Comment: This module is active? Also try removing cache properly and run upgrade and compile command.

Comment: thanks, it's solved. but an other problem appeared:  
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
can you help please

Comment: In which file you are getting this error?

Comment: It doesn't specify a file

Comment: Please attach its screenshot.

Comment: here it's 
https://www.pastepic.xyz/image/pIvNJ

Comment: Check logs if there is anything else

Comment: Thanks very much. logs really helped me. And sorry for late reply

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped you :)